# No known class method for selector notificationCenterVibrancyEffect iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uiblureffect

I'm trying out `UIBlurEffect` and `UIVibrancyEffect` for a view.

Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVibrancyEffect/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIVibrancyEffect/notificationCenterVibrancyEffect) claim a "notificationCenterVibrancyEffect", but even after importing UIKit in my class, it throws `No known class method for selector notificationCenterVibrancyEffect`.

Code looks like this, every other class method resolves just fine:

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVibrancyEffect *vibrancyEffect = [UIVibrancyEffect notificationCenterVibrancyEffect];
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
UIVisualEffectView *vibrancyEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:vibrancyEffect];
```

Comment: What version of iOS are you using?  This is documented to be in "iOS 8.0 or later".

Comment: Sorry, thought that was clear - yes all targets are set to iOS 8

Comment: Are you interacting with Swift at all? The docs only show that method available for Obj-C which is odd.

Comment: No, no Swift - and what's really odd is I saw someone write a gist using it in Swift :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only available for "Today" extensions. If you create a new target in your project of the class "Today" extensions and you add your code to the view controller, it will build fine.

The method `+ (UIVibrancyEffect *)notificationCenterVibrancyEffect;` is declared in a category of the class `UIVibrancyEffect` named `NotificationCenter`, and declared in the NotificationCenter framework, in a header file called `NCWidgetProviding.h`

Try: `#import <NotificationCenter/NotificationCenter.h>` in your view controller, I was able to build a sample project with your code this way.